# Open Engineer Mode and run other hidden codes on Moto G 3rd generation device?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, lineageos, dialer-codes, motorola-moto-g3

I'm running LineageOS ROM on my Moto G 3rd generation smartphone and recently I wanted to run some hidden codes of Android like `*#06#` for IMEI and so on.
However, none of this [ones](https://www.hardreset.info/devices/motorola/motorola-moto-g-3rd-generation-xt1550/codes/) works correctly on my phone:

> 1. Phone information
>      `*#*#4636#*#*`
> 2. IMEI Info
>      `*#06#`
> 3. Calendar
>      `*#*#225#*#*`
> 4. Debug info for Google Play Service
>      `*#*#426#*#*`
> 5. Access Google Partner Setup
>      `*#*#759#*#*`
> 6. Engineering Mode
>      `*#*#2486#*#*`

The IMEI closes the dealer/phone app, while the engineer/service mode codes (the one in which I'm more interested) don't activate anything. Let's say that the dealer interprets correctly the code but doesn't run this tasks.

So knowing this, I would like to know if there is a way of looking if the relative services are on my phone? If it isn't the case, how I can add them or run from PC with USB maybe? Are the secret codes dependent on the ROM like I imagine or not?

#### Notes:

I tried hidden codes of other manufacturers like Samsung, HTC, ... too but no result obviously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These dialer codes all vary by OEM in their stock ROM's... the codes for stock firmware are often easily accessible via searching the Internet or via apps available from various sources. However, how custom ROM makers handle these codes, if they implement them at all, is an entirely different thing again.

There are some standard-ish codes, like `*#06#`, but even this is not consistent across all devices in all cases. There isn't really a standard for other codes nor is there any incentive for OEMs or ROM developers to even implement many of them.

Many dialer codes are also passed to the carrier, for things like Call Forwarding, checking your balance of money or minutes, blocking Caller ID, activating Call Waiting, etc... although there are some standards, actually commonality more than a standard, between some carriers, these are entirely carrier dependent as well on how and if they implement them.

To answer your questions specifically, well, as specifically as possible...

> I would like to know if there is a way of looking if the relative
>   services are on my phone? If it isn't the case, how I can add them or
>   run from PC with USB maybe?

Unfortunately, no... these are device and ROM dependent. I would suggest posting in the official support thread for your device and specific ROM to see if they have implemented in any way or there are alternatives that are specific to your ROM, device, and use case.

> Are the secret codes dependent on the ROM like I imagine or not?

Yes, they absolutely are...

Source: Years of being an Android enthusiast, ROM developer, and XDA Recognized Contributor. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're rooted and have `busybox` and `aapt` installed on your device, then this little script might help reveal a lot of the ROM built-in codes.

To be run at root shell prompt on the device. All one single line.

```
busybox find /system/ -name '*.apk' -exec aapt dump xmltree {} AndroidManifest.xml \; | busybox awk '/android_secret_code/{getline;sub(/^.*="/,"");sub(/".*$/,"");print}'
```